# Why is the 'in' operator in pycharm failing me?

Tags: python, boolean, operator-keyword

New to Python,and maybe this is the wrong place.

Thx a bunch.

```
fff = dict()

fff["Stan"] = 1

fff["Dave"] = 1

fff["Scott"] = 1

print (fff)

"John" in fff
```

When I run the code, this is the result:

> {'Stan': 1, 'Dave': 1, 'Scott': 1}

Process finished with exit code 0

Expected a `False`, but it just ignores the last line

Comment: You need to print a value if you want it to appear in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `print`: Replace `"John" in fff` with `print("John" in fff)`.

Other comments: use better variable names and replace `fff = dict()` with `fff = {}`.